# Chidamber-Kemerer on sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I'd like to know if Chidamber-Kemerer object oriented metrics are available for Sonarqube(v.4.5). Not found in plugins, but I've checked in previous releases that it was available:http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-2-0-in-screenshots/

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
Javier

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the public JIRA of SonarQube, we indeed progressively removed those metrics as they are not easy to correctly compute, understand and interpret, which inevitably leads to many false-positives:

- SQ 3.2: [Remove the "Chidamber & Kemerer" from the default project dashboard](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3451)
- SQ 4.1: [Remove support of LCOM4](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4853)
- SQ 4.2: [Deprecate RFC metric](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5042)

Comment: The statement is very arguable and, since the links do not work properly now, I encourage you to edit your answer. Thank you!